# Inserting dynamic value into array of objects, javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, iterator, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects that look something like this;

```
[
{Number: 5002000, Origin: 123456, Count: 128},
{Number: 5002300, Origin: 900231, Count: 52},
{Number: 5002022, Origin: 534323, Count: 269}
]
```

Now I'm trying to multiply the "Count" value with a value from a designated price pool.

Which looks something like this;

```
[
{Prefix: 50023, Price: 20},    
{Prefix: 50020, Price: 10},
{Prefix: 5002, Price: 60},
]
```

Currently there's an horrendous for loop with if-statements.

```
for (var key in sData) {
  if (sData[key].Origin.startsWith('50023')) {
    sData[key].sum = (sData[key].Count * 20);
  }
  else if (sData[key].Origin.startsWith('50020')) {
    sData[key].sum = (sData[key].Count * 10);
  }
  // continues...
}
```

startsWith is a function that simply checks if the value starts with the (value).

Is there already a function in JS to map two arrays of objects? (I'm also having issues with the logic since the "Prefix" value basically has to go from the top down as not to land on the default "5002"-prefix.)

Comment: but the prefix `5002` covers the rest of prefixes. What is the priority?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use nested loops in this situation. Also switch to `Array.forEach` method.

```
sData.forEach(function(item_, key) {

          prices.forEach(function(item) {

             if (sData[key].Origin.startsWith(item.Prefix)) {
                sData[key].sum = (sData[key].Count * item.Price);
             }

          });  

 })
```

Comment: Right, that was simple, let me try!

Comment: As your manipulating the item in the `sData` array a [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) would be preferable over `forEach`

Comment: @ste2425 - map method creates a new array. But here the OP needs to modify the original.

Comment: @CharlieH I missed that fact my bad, however you could do `sData = sData.map(x => {})`. `Map` is meant for manipulating the arrays contents, `forEach` for iterating. But on the flip side `sData = sData.map(x => {})` does look ugly.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that second array can be transformed into the hash:

```
var tiers = {
    50023: {Prefix: 50023, Price: 20},    
    50020: {Prefix: 50020, Price: 10},
    5002: {Prefix: 5002, Price: 60},
}
```

You may make it look like this:

```
for (var key in sData) {
    var key = String(sData[key])
    var keyIndex = key.slice(5)

    if (tiers.hasOwnProperty(keyIndex)) {
        var price = tiers[keyIndex].Price
        sData[key].sum = (sData[key].Count * price)
    } else {
        // Fallback solution
    }
}
```

Going further you may even think of some recursive solution for fallback.